# BizTalk 2020 with MQSC adapter Cancel message

Tags: ibm-mq, biztalk, biztalk-2020

I'm migrating a BizTalk 2013 R2 env to BizTalk 2020 and facing an issue with the adapter MQSC. The flow uses the IBM client installed with Host Integration 2020. When restarting Host instances, receive location receive randomly a cancel message that ends with a routing failure:

[image]

When I switch to IBM .Net client, I receive another cancel message :

[image]

regarding MQ properties this message is putted by BizTalk:

[image]

is there a way to avoid receiving this message?

Comment: Yup.  I have had customers recently ask me about it.  All I know is that it is BizTalk putting the message.  I haven't figured out how to turn it off.

Comment: What happens to the message?  Does it suspend?  Does it have a routing failure?

Comment: Are there any other context properties in the message that you could use to route these messages when they occur?

Comment: the message has a routing failure, yes I can route it but it's not clean. I exchanged with MS support  they will may provide me a fix for this problem. I'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue related to performance and timeout where MQSC adapter during a receive operation is waiting for messages with longer timeout (to avoid extra network traffic polling too often). When someone wants to stop BizTalk host instance or MQSC receive location it had to wait for the timeout, and users would be impatient killing host instance before it had time to receive the timeout. Then an extra CANCEL message was sent from the receive code to the same queue when stop signal event was signalled to be able to get control back from receive location and being able to finish and stop the receive location. In certain situations with custom pipelines or other errors these internal CANCEL messages could accidentally surface up in suspended messages as well instead of being discarded properly in the shutdown of receive location/host instance. This has been resolved and improved in later HIS 2020 updates, e g CU1.
You can just delete this extra Cancel message in case you haven't got latest update yet and it should appear.